# Create symlinks sorted by year folders

Tags: bash, shell

I have a holiday folder with all pictures unsorted in the same folder, all files are tagged with the year. I want to create a folder for the year. This I've solved with:

```
#!/bin/bash

SOURCE=/path/to/pictures

cd ~/pictures/sorted.by.year/
ls $SOURCE | grep -o -P '(?<!\d)\d{4}(?!\d)' | tr '/' '\n' | sort |
uniq | xargs mkdir
```

Now to my problem, I want to create a symlink to all year folders from the filename so it will create symlinks, like this:

~/pictures/sorted.by.year/**2014**/symlink-picture.on.sister.**2014**.jpg

~/pictures/sorted.by.year/**2012**/symlink-picture.on.dad.**2012**.jpg

I have tried with `xargs` but the result was not as I wanted in the example above.

Does someone have an idea how to do it?

Comment: Is it correct to deduce that you have a file `/path/to/pictures/picture.on.sister.2014.jpg` and you want a symlink `~/pictures/sorted.by.year/2014/symlink-picture.on.sister.2014.jpg` that points to the original file?  Are there any extra directory levels to worry about?

Comment: You've understood it perfect. I want it in some kind of loop that should point to the original file yes. No deeper directories just want them sorted in my year folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this script, I added some more line after your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
SOURCE=/path/to/pictures

cd ~/pictures/sorted.by.year/
ls $SOURCE | grep -o -P '(?<!\d)\d{4}(?!\d)' | tr '/' '\n' | sort | uniq | xargs mkdir

for file in /path/to/pictures/*
do
    if [[ -d $file ]]; then # Skip directory
        continue;
    fi
    DIRNAME=$(echo "$file" | grep -o -P '(?<!\d)\d{4}(?!\d)');
    ln -s "$file" "./$DIRNAME/"
done
```